# Creating a file using Pico under a different directory

Tags: unix

If I am trying to create a file name `"Data01"` using the [Pico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pico_(text_editor)) editor with the contents of `"Data File Number 01"` on one line.

However my current directory is
`csc209/asgn06`

I need to create these files in
`csc209/asgn06/test01` without changing directories in one command. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prefix the filename with a relative path. If the directory exists:

```
pico test01/Data01
```

Otherwise, first create it with:

```
mkdir test01
```

then proceed as above.